# How to prepend a common prefix to all URLs before the controller in ASP.NET API?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET API project where I have multiple controllers, and I want to prepend a common prefix to all the URLs before the controller route. For example, I want all my API endpoints to have the prefix "/appapi/" followed by the controller name.

I know that I can achieve this by manually adding the prefix in each controller using the `[Route]`attribute, like `[Route("appapi/MyController")]`. However, this requires updating every controller, which can be time-consuming and error-prone.

Is there a more efficient and centralized way to add this common prefix to all the URLs without modifying each controller individually? I want to avoid duplicating the prefix in multiple places and have a single configuration or setup that applies it to all controllers.

I'm using ASP.NET 6.0 and have already tried using `app.UsePathBase("/appapi")` in the Configure method of my `Program.cs` file, but it didn't prepend the prefix to the URLs as expected.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

`app.UseRouting(); app.UsePathBase("/appapi");`

Comment: Could you not use URLREWRITE in IIS to do this automatically ?  Citation -->
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more efficient and centralized way to add this common
> prefix to all the URLs without modifying each controller individually?
> I want to avoid duplicating the prefix in multiple places and have a
> single configuration or setup that applies it to all controllers.

Of course you can, in fact, using `app.UsePathBase` we can achieve that. But based on your shared code snippet and description it seems that, your configuration is not correct. Within `UsePathBase` middleware we have to pass our new route value in order to set a global route prefix with all the existing controller.

Here is the correct way:

Program.cs:

```cs
app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/appapi"));
app.UseRouting();

app.Run();
```

**Note:** As you can see I am passing the prefix using new route prefix and also your controller should have route name as your controller only.

Demo Controller:

```cs
    [Route("RoutePrefixTest")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RoutePrefixTestController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult GetCity()
        {
            var checkBaseRoutePath = HttpContext.Request.PathBase;

            var cityList = new List<City>()
            {
                new City { Id = 101, Name = "Alberta" },
                new City { Id = 102, Name = "Toronto" },
                new City { Id = 103, Name = "British Comlombia" },
            };
            return Ok(cityList);
        }
    }
```

Demo Modeel:

```cs
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to edit your `MapControllerRoute` middleware:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "myportal/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Here, `myportal` is prefixed to each route automatically.

And also edit `UseStaticFiles` middleware

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    RequestPath = "/myportal"
});
```